# Spring custom @Cacheable annotation using @AliasFor

Tags: spring, caching, annotations

I'm trying to write an annotation that is itself annotated with `@Cacheable`.  The goal is to add a few more attributes that I later access when manually initializing my caches.  At first glance it will seem similar to [Writing a custom Spring @Cacheable annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949265/writing-a-custom-spring-cacheable-annotation), but I'm trying to use `@AliasFor` instead of going down the parser route.

Here's what I have so far:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Inherited
@Cacheable
public @interface CacheableLocal {
    @AliasFor(annotation = Cacheable.class, attribute = "value") 
    String[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = Cacheable.class, attribute = "cacheNames") 
    String[] cacheNames() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = Cacheable.class, attribute = "key") 
    String key() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = Cacheable.class, attribute = "keyGenerator") 
    String keyGenerator() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = Cacheable.class, attribute = "condition") 
    String condition() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = Cacheable.class, attribute = "unless") 
    String unless() default "";

    int maxEntries() default 100;

    long ttlSeconds() default 1800L;
}
```

and I had hoped to use this new annotation like this:

```
@CacheableLocal(cacheNames = "dictionary", maxEntries = 300, ttlSeconds = 1800)
public String getDefinition(String word) {
    ...
}
```

The problem that I've run into is that the `cacheNames` value isn't associated to the `@Cacheable` meta-annotation despite the presence of `@AliasFor`.  So while I can see that Spring correctly finds the `@Cacheable` meta-annotation that is on my `@CacheableLocal` annotation when synthesizing, it doesn't consider the values that should be set.

It's similar to a recently reported Spring bug https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13475.  It's not exactly the same, so I'm hoping that I'm just doing it wrong and there's an easy solution other than waiting for Spring 4.3  :)

Comment: I'm afraid the JIRA issue addresses exactly your problem. Have a look at the `@Ignored` test `singleComposedAnnotation` [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/test/java/org/springframework/cache/annotation/AnnotationCacheOperationSourceTests.java#L375)

Comment: Yes, I think you're right.  I also tried using the JSR-107 annotations like `@CacheResult` instead of `@Cacheable`, but they're not considered as meta-annotations so it didn't help me.  Guess I'll have to wait for 4.3.