# Spring Boot | Create custom caching annotation and implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-cache

I want to create a custom spring @Cachable annotation, where i can defined the expire time in seconds. 
The problem is, i don't know how i implement the new method "expiresInSec()" in the custom annotation.

Here is my custom @Cachable annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(
{ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Cachable
{
    Cacheable cachable();

    // cache entry expires in 1 hour by default
    int expiresInSec() default 3600;
}
```

This is the call of custom annotation:

```
@Cachable(cachable = @Cacheable("WorkListRepository::getWorkList"), expiresInSec = 60)
```

But the expireInSec parameter doesn't work. Where i must implementing this parameter method.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the Spring [`Cacheable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) would require more than just adding extra attributes in the annotation. You need to extends the capabilities of annotation processor for caching in Spring as well. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949265/writing-a-custom-spring-cacheable-annotation) for more details on what it would take.

Spring caching is an abstraction and requires a cache provider and generally the expiry is set on the cache level ( for e.g, [Ehcache](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/configuration/data-life.html) has `timeToLiveSeconds`  parameter for each cache)

Comment: If i use Ehcache, then i must create a xml file for configuration of each cache. Is that correct?

Comment: And can i use Ehcache as well as spring cache? With the annotations?

Comment: You will have to use some provider. Spring boot checks the dependencies on classpath to automatically determine the provider. E.g. you may have mentioned Ehcache in your build file then Spring boot will at runtime check the provider jar. However by default Spring boot  Ehcache integration will  not get initilized until a configuration file ( by default ehcache.xml is not provided). Check here for an example with TTL with Ehcache and Spring boot. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-ehcache

Comment: Yes i've found this page of baeldung too, but i must create a xml file for expiry of cache. I want to define the expiry of a cache over the @Cachable annotation.